# How to load .profile without relogin in AIX?

Tags: aix, profile

How can I load my `.profile` file without a relogin in AIX Server?

Comment: Related: [how do i tell gnome to reread my ~/.profile](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2949/12779) and [How to change environment variables without re-logging to UI?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43638/12779)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply source it:

```
. ~/.profile
```

Or do a login with `su -l <user>`, this doesn't require a logout.

Comment: In the case of `su -l <user>`, the options `-`, `-l` and `--login` are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

```
source ~/.profile
```

and

```
. ~/.profile
```